# Why do we get a weird method name when calling kotlin object from java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In kotlin I have a class that was converted to an object and now when I call it from java the method name is appended with $app. What does this mean?

**Kotlin**

```
object SomeObject {
    internal val standardRetroService: WebPredictionService
        get() = getCustomBaseRetroService(CloudUtil.doStuff)
}
```

**Java**

```
SomeObject.INSTANCE.getStandardRetroService$app().dostuff();
```

Comment: You can take a look at what `SomeObject` compiles into from a Java perspective by opening that source file and using Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin bytecode -> Decompile.

Comment: Because you added `internal`. And you didn't add `@JvmStatic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that postfix because of the `internal` visibility modifer, which makes the property visible only within its module (`app`) when using it from Kotlin.

There isn't such a visibility in Java / on the bytecode level, so instead the identifier gets "mangled" with this this postfix, which is supposed to signal to Java clients that they shouldn't be using it, at least if they aren't sure they know what they're doing.

Comment: This makes sense as the code proved to have some errors. Was a java to kotlin conversion gone wrong :)

Comment: To be exact, it had been made internal from default in java.

Comment: Yes, the converter seems to like to turn things with for example package visibility to explicitly `internal`.